# How to access active admin page without login in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, phantomjs

I want to capture the screen shot of a page in the active admin but when i am trying this it's asking for login ? is it possible to take screen shot without login using PhantomJS?
It is working fine if i am capture the screen shot of public url like from inside our application but when trying to access it takes the screen shot of login page.

Answer (score 0):

You want to access a page that is password/session protected.

This means you must create a session, make it known to your "browser" (PhantomJS), and *then* make your screenshot.

You can do this using the gems `capybara` (web test framework) plus `poltergeist` (PhantomJS adapter) (by orchestrating an actual login with a test account on your development machine). If you want to go all out, add `cucumber` to the mix (which does not help you with this simple task, but is a nice addition to your stack as software developer).

For more information on those gems, see their respective web sites, mostly github pages. All three are very well documented. If you have a specific question after that, feel free to ask again.

Of course, if you want to make it as quick and dirty as possible, nobody keeps you from simply monkey-patching the session check away for this purpose.